# Permissions for users accessing website via LAN (Django)

Tags: django, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am stuck on this problem. 
The Idea is to allow users accessing my website through the LAN or local network to skip a login page and access the website as an anonymous user with special permissions. (I am running an ubuntu server with apache2 and mod_wsgi). Does anyone know if there is a way for apache to determine if a user is accessing the website via LAN? I am open to all suggestions as I currently have no idea how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just look at the remote IP. If it's in your LAN subnet, then you know they're local. However, usual disclaimers and all: while REMOTE_ADDR is *for the most part* safe to use, it *can* be spoofed under certain circumstances. It would require access to an ISP or similar (a level of hacking only worthwhile if you were trying to penetrate a bank and make off with enough to hide out in a some secluded island resort for the rest of your life), or access to the local network itself, so it's a bit fanciful in either scenario, but the golden rule of security is "plan for the worst, hope for the best". *Any* intrusion scenario is generally too high a price to pay for whatever minor convenience the lack of security grants you.

That said, I'll treat this as an educational exercise. You'd still need at least one user that would simply be shared among all the local network users (another honkin' big red security flag, by the way). You would check the IP address, determine if it's in your subnet, and if so, log in the shared user using stored credentials (yet another honkin' big red security flag).

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

class PleaseHackMeMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if re.search(r'^192.168.1', request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']):
            user = authenticate('shared_username', 'shared_password')
            if user:
                login(request, user)
```

Then, just add that to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and wait for something bad to happen.

Comment: yeah something like that,  or just deny access from apache or os level.

Comment: That will work, I will keep this open and try to think of a more secure way to do this as security is an issue with this website. I wonder if creating a temporary user for the duration of their session might solve the security issue of having a shared user?

Comment: Also I was thinking of making different virtual hosts on the server. One for all public access running on a different port which a DNS server can reroute the website to, and the other running on port 80. The non-public virtual host running on port 80 could pass a variable into the website through wsgi telling the website the user is on LAN somehow?

Comment: You'd still need a way of authenticating them, but only allowing access under a particular domain or port or both that is only accessible via the local intranet is a good step towards locking it down. In that case, you can simply check for the port or the domain instead of the IP address, and your network firewall then becomes responsible for restricting access to either one.